# Extraer una lista de los nombres de un archivo rar por medio de c#

Tags: c#, consola

Buen día,

Estoy tratando de extraer el listado de los archivos que contiene un archivo .rar, he buscado varias soluciones y no encuentro como hacerlo desde c#, la única opción que encontró fue por medio de consola utilizando el siguiente codigo.

```
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        //proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
        proc.Start();
        proc.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"rar l E:\test.rar >> E:\test.csv");
        proc.StandardInput.Flush();
        //proc.StandardInput.Close();
        proc.Close(); 
    }
```

La linea "rar l E:\test.rar >> E:\test.csv" funciona correctamente en consola, previo a utilizarla copie el archivo rar.exe que se genera al instalar winrar en mi maquina, en la carpeta del System32.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código me genera el siguiente error al ejecutarlo desde C#.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito ayuda por favor.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Comment: En cuanto a tu pregunta, el problema parece obvio. `rar.exe` no se encuentra en el path ni tampoco en la carpeta donde se ejecuta tu aplicación. O bien copias el rar.exe a la ruta de la aplicacion, o puedes añadir el path completo del rar.exe en lo que estas ejecutando, o bien puedes usar la propiedad [WorkingDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) de `ProcessStartInfo` para definir sobre que carpeta quieres que trabaje tu aplicacion

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me funciono super bien copiandolo en la ruta de la aplicación.

Comment: En realidad como solucion sirve. pero no probaste con ninguna de las multiples librerias que hay en nuget para abrir este tipo de archivos?

Comment: Si me pudieras recomendar alguna te lo agradecería muchisimo, he estado intentando de varias maneras y honestamente no he encontrado solución y también debo de hacerlo para un .zip

Comment: Yo en alguna ocasión he utilizado SharpCompress (https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpCompress/) (continuación de NUnrar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe una librería llamada sharpcompress, la puedes encontrar en [GitHub](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress/blob/master/USAGE.md)

Tiene varias funciones y es posible que te facilite la tarea sin tener que hacer uso del CMD

Comment: Muchas gracias revisare la librería para ver si me funciona para lo que necesito.